# The widget of bottom frame goes to top frame while scrolling down. tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have copied a code online which provides good calendar widget in tkinter. But in one of the pages, when you scroll down the frame, the calendar in below frame goes to the frame which is in the top. Here is the code for the calendar:

```
class Calendar(ttk.Frame):
    # XXX ToDo: cget and configure

    datetime = calendar.datetime.datetime
    timedelta = calendar.datetime.timedelta

    def get_calendar(self,locale, fwday):
        # instantiate proper calendar class
        if locale is None:
            return calendar.TextCalendar(fwday)
        else:
            return calendar.LocaleTextCalendar(fwday, locale)

    def __init__(self,entryvariable, master, **kw):
        """
        WIDGET-SPECIFIC OPTIONS

            locale, firstweekday, year, month, selectbackground,
            selectforeground
        """
        # remove custom options from kw before initializating ttk.Frame
        fwday = kw.pop('firstweekday', calendar.MONDAY)
        year = kw.pop('year', self.datetime.now().year)
        month = kw.pop('month', self.datetime.now().month)
        locale = kw.pop('locale', None)
        sel_bg = kw.pop('selectbackground', '#ecffc4')
        sel_fg = kw.pop('selectforeground', '#05640e')

        self._date = self.datetime(year, month, 1)
        self._selection = None # no date selected
        self.entryvariable=entryvariable
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self,master, **kw)

        self._cal = self.get_calendar(locale, fwday)

        self.__setup_styles()       # creates custom styles
        self.__place_widgets()      # pack/grid used widgets
        self.__config_calendar()    # adjust calendar columns and setup tags
        # confizgure a canvas, and proper bindings, for selecting dates
        self.__setup_selection(sel_bg, sel_fg)

        # store items ids, used for insertion later
        self._items = [self._calendar.insert('', 'end', values='')
                            for _ in range(6)]
        # insert dates in the currently empty calendar
        self._build_calendar()

        # set the minimal size for the widget
        self._calendar.bind('<Map>', self.__minsize)

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        if item in ('year', 'month'):
            raise AttributeError("attribute '%s' is not writeable" % item)
        elif item == 'selectbackground':
            self._canvas['background'] = value
        elif item == 'selectforeground':
            self._canvas.itemconfigure(self._canvas.text, item=value)
        else:
            ttk.Frame.__setitem__(self, item, value)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if item in ('year', 'month'):
            return getattr(self._date, item)
        elif item == 'selectbackground':
            return self._canvas['background']
        elif item == 'selectforeground':
            return self._canvas.itemcget(self._canvas.text, 'fill')
        else:
            r = ttk.tclobjs_to_py({item: ttk.Frame.__getitem__(self, item)})
            return r[item]

    def __setup_styles(self):
        # custom ttk styles
        style = ttk.Style(self.master)
        arrow_layout = lambda dir: (
            [('Button.focus', {'children': [('Button.%sarrow' % dir, None)]})]
        )
        style.layout('L.TButton', arrow_layout('left'))
        style.layout('R.TButton', arrow_layout('right'))

    def __place_widgets(self):
        # header frame and its widgets
        hframe = ttk.Frame(self)
        lbtn = ttk.Button(hframe, style='L.TButton', command=self._prev_month)
        rbtn = ttk.Button(hframe, style='R.TButton', command=self._next_month)
        self._header = ttk.Label(hframe, width=15, anchor='center')
        # the calendar
        self._calendar = ttk.Treeview(show='', selectmode='none', height=7)

        # pack the widgets
        hframe.pack(in_=self, side='top', pady=4, anchor='center')
        lbtn.grid(in_=hframe)
        self._header.grid(in_=hframe, column=1, row=0, padx=12)
        rbtn.grid(in_=hframe, column=2, row=0)
        self._calendar.pack(in_=self, expand=1, fill='both', side='bottom')

    def __config_calendar(self):
        cols = self._cal.formatweekheader(3).split()
        self._calendar['columns'] = cols
        self._calendar.tag_configure('header', background='grey90')
        self._calendar.insert('', 'end', values=cols, tag='header')
        # adjust its columns width
        font = tkFont.Font()
        maxwidth = max(font.measure(col) for col in cols)
        for col in cols:
            self._calendar.column(col, width=maxwidth, minwidth=maxwidth,
                anchor='e')

    def __setup_selection(self, sel_bg, sel_fg):
        self._font = tkFont.Font()
        self._canvas = canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(self._calendar,
            background=sel_bg, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        canvas.text = canvas.create_text(0, 0, fill=sel_fg, anchor='w')

        canvas.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', lambda evt: canvas.place_forget())
        self._calendar.bind('<Configure>', lambda evt: canvas.place_forget())
        self._calendar.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self._pressed)

    def __minsize(self, evt):
        width, height = self._calendar.master.geometry().split('x')
        height = height[:height.index('+')]
        self._calendar.master.minsize(width, height)

    def _build_calendar(self):
        year, month = self._date.year, self._date.month
        # update header text (Month, YEAR)
        header = self._cal.formatmonthname(year, month, 0)
        self._header['text'] = header.title()

        # update calendar shown dates
        cal = self._cal.monthdayscalendar(year, month)
        for indx, item in enumerate(self._items):
            week = cal[indx] if indx < len(cal) else []
            fmt_week = [('%02d' % day) if day else '' for day in week]
            self._calendar.item(item, values=fmt_week)

    def _show_selection(self, text, bbox):
        """Configure canvas for a new selection."""
        x, y, width, height = bbox

        textw = self._font.measure(text)

        canvas = self._canvas
        canvas.configure(width=width, height=height)
        canvas.coords(canvas.text, width - textw, height / 2 - 1)
        canvas.itemconfigure(canvas.text, text=text)
        canvas.place(in_=self._calendar, x=x, y=y)

    # Callbacks

    def _pressed(self, evt):
        """Clicked somewhere in the calendar."""
        x, y, widget = evt.x, evt.y, evt.widget
        item = widget.identify_row(y)
        column = widget.identify_column(x)

        if not column or not item in self._items:
            # clicked in the weekdays row or just outside the columns
            return

        item_values = widget.item(item)['values']
        if not len(item_values): # row is empty for this month
            return

        text = item_values[int(column[1]) - 1]
        if not text: # date is empty
            return

        bbox = widget.bbox(item, column)
        if not bbox: # calendar not visible yet
            return

        # update and then show selection
        #text1 = '%02d-%02M-02Y' % text
        text = '%02d' % text
        #text1='%02d-%02M-02Y'%text
        self._selection = (text, item, column)
        self._show_selection(text, bbox)
        self.entryvariable.set(self.selection.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
        print(self.selection)

    def _prev_month(self):
        """Updated calendar to show the previous month."""
        self._canvas.place_forget()

        self._date = self._date - self.timedelta(days=1)
        self._date = self.datetime(self._date.year, self._date.month, 1)
        self._build_calendar() # reconstuct calendar

    def _next_month(self):
        """Update calendar to show the next month."""
        self._canvas.place_forget()

        year, month = self._date.year, self._date.month
        self._date = self._date + self.timedelta(
            days=calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1] + 1)
        self._date = self.datetime(self._date.year, self._date.month, 1)
        self._build_calendar() # reconstruct calendar

    # Properties

    @property
    def selection(self):
        """Return a datetime representing the current selected date."""
        if not self._selection:
            return None

        year, month = self._date.year, self._date.month
        return self.datetime(year, month, int(self._selection[0]))

class date_entry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, master,*args, **kwargs):
        Entry.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.var = self["textvariable"]
        if self.var == '':
            self.var = self["textvariable"] = StringVar(master)

        self.ttkcal = Calendar(master=master,firstweekday=calendar.SUNDAY,entryvariable=self.var)

    def pack(self,*args, **kwargs):
        Entry.pack(self,*args, **kwargs)
        print(self.winfo_x()," ",self.winfo_y())
        self.ttkcal.place(x=self.winfo_x() + 40, y=self.winfo_y() + self.winfo_height() + 40)
    def grid(self,date_row,date_column,*args, **kwargs):
        Entry.grid(self,*args, **kwargs)
        self.ttkcal.grid(row=date_row,column=date_column,columnspan=2,rowspan=4)
```

This is used in the code here:

```
    F1 = Frame(root1,width=1050, height=500, relief="sunken")
    #F1.config(width=1050, height=650)
    F1.pack_propagate(0)
    F1.pack(side=LEFT)

    canvas = scrollbar()
    root = canvas.createcanvas(F1)
    .....
    label = Label(f1, text="Bill Date:", borderwidth=1, relief="solid", background="black", foreground="white")
    label.config(width=20)
    label.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky='W')
    self.date_entry = date_entry(f1,f1)
    self.date_entry.grid(date_row=1,date_column=3,row=0, column=4, columnspan=1, sticky='W')
    label = Label(f1, text="Delivery Date:", borderwidth=1, relief="solid", background="black", foreground="white")
    label.config(width=20)
    label.grid(row=0, column=5, sticky='W')
    self.deliverydate_entry = date_entry(f1,f1)
    self.deliverydate_entry.grid(date_row=1,date_column=5,row=0, column=6, columnspan=1, sticky='W')
```

The resulting issue is in the screenshot attached. [The date calendar which should be in below frame, goes to top frame while scrolling down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVNew.jpg).

Comment: This seems like way too much code. Please try to condense it down into a [mcve]

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code - it will add 4 spaces before **every** line of code

Comment: problem may means that calendar has wrong parent/master and it is not below frame but inside frame.

Comment: Thanks. Actually if you look at the code, you can see that I have done my own modifications so as to make sure the widget parent is the below frame. But even after that there is no  choice. I have added all the code for better understanding. Main action point is the grid function which places the calendar. since it is correctly placed in the date_row=1, date_column=5 I think the parent is actually the same frame. Please help.